# Debian using ./configure to install tcpdump-3.9.8

Tags: openssl, debian

I downloaded the tcpdump source file to build it manually. When I run ./configure it gives the following error:

```
checking if unaligned accesses fail... no
checking for h_errno... yes
./configure: line 12852: syntax error near unexpected token `LIBSSL,'
./configure: line 12852: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(LIBSSL, libssl)'
```

I do have the `libssl-dev` and `openssl` installed and google search could not help much.

Some Config.log file errors below:

```
configure:3283: gcc -E  -O2 conftest.c
conftest.c:10:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
#include <ac_nonexistent.h>
        compilation terminated.

configure:3388: gcc -E  -O2 conftest.c
conftest.c:10:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
#include <ac_nonexistent.h>

conftest.c:54:24: fatal error: rpc/rpcent.h: No such file or directory
#include <rpc/rpcent.h>

configure:3910: gcc -E  -O2 conftest.c
conftest.c:21:24: fatal error: rpc/rpcent.h: No such file or directory
#include <rpc/rpcent.h>
```

Comment: Please post the releavnt sample program logged by Autoconf in `config.log`.

Comment: It's a really long log file.